# Why doesn't special extra requires :test: work?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I am trying to implement the special `:test:` extras using `pip` and `setuptools` as specified in [PEP 426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#extras-optional-dependencies).

I have created the following `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.0.0',
    tests_require=['requests'])
```

Running `./setup.py bdist_wheel` gives me a wheel with the following `metadata.json`:

```
{
  "name": "spam",
  "test_requires": [
    {
      "requires": [
        "requests"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "python.details": {
      "document_names": {
        "description": "DESCRIPTION.rst"
      }
    }
  },
  "summary": "UNKNOWN",
  "generator": "bdist_wheel (0.24.0)",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "metadata_version": "2.0"
}
```

I expected to be able to install the `test_requires` by specifying the extra `:test:`. However, this gets me the following output:

```
$ pip install spam-0.0.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl\[:test:\]
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/5221/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/5221/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
    name, None, isolated=options.isolated_mode,
  File "/tmp/5221/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 179, in from_line
    isolated=isolated)
  File "/tmp/5221/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 52, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/tmp/5221/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2873, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/tmp/5221/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2816, in parse_requirements
    DISTRO, CBRACKET, line, p, (1,), "'extra' name"
  File "/tmp/5221/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2785, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ("Expected 'extra' name in", 'spam-0.0.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl[:test:]', 'at', ':test:]')
```

The same happens when trying to install the project using `pip install -e .\[:test:\]`

It doesn't matter whether I use Python 2.7 or 3.4. I did everything using an up-to-date virtualenv (`pip == 6.0.6`, `setuptools == 12.0.4`, `wheel == 0.24.0`)

What am I doing wrong?